# A way to maintain cell references when doing dynamic running total

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, cumulative-sum

I have a running total of another dynamically generated column (I7:I). I computed it using `mmult()`. The only problem with this is using indirect means the references break if I move data around in my sheet say by adding or removing rows above 7. If I use I7:I as my reference, it says the resulting array is too large. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
=ArrayFormula( MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(indirect("I7:I" & max(ArrayFormula(ROW(I6:I)*(I6:I <> "")))) )<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(indirect("I7:I" & max(ArrayFormula(ROW(I6:I)*(I6:I <> "")))) )))*indirect("I7:I" & max(ArrayFormula(ROW(I6:I)*(I6:I <> "")))) ),query(indirect("I7:I" & max(ArrayFormula(ROW(I6:I)*(I6:I <> "")))),  "select 1 label 1 ''")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(
 TRANSPOSE((ROW(INDIRECT("I7:I"&MAX(ROW(I:I)*($I:$I<>""))))<=
 TRANSPOSE( ROW(INDIRECT("I7:I"&MAX(ROW(I:I)*($I:$I<>""))))))*
                INDIRECT("I7:I"&MAX(ROW(I:I)*($I:$I<>"")))),
          QUERY(INDIRECT("I7:I"&MAX(ROW(I:I)*($I:$I<>""))),  
 "select 1 label 1''")))
```

[image: 0]